# Need for two level reference in T-SQL

Tags: sql, ssms

By using the dynamic SQL, I created a variable name like this:

```
set @tempresultStore = 'Temp'+@colVar
```

Now, `@tempresultstore` has the value 'TempMiddleName', then I declared this variable named TempMiddleName and assigned the value in the same line in dynamic sql query and executed.

The code is as follows :(Scroll down to code line with comment to follow where the problem is)

```
    CREATE Procedure OutputProcedure

     @LastNameFromUser nvarchar(20) = null, 
     @LastNameFromTable nvarchar(20), 
     @MiddleNameFromUser nvarchar(20) = null, 
     @MiddleNameFromTable nvarchar(20) = null, 
     @CityFromUser nvarchar(20) = null,
      @CityFromTable nvarchar(20) = null,
    @Percentage int out

    AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT @MiddleNameFromTable AS'middlename'
    select @LastNameFromTable as 'LASTNAMEFROMTABLE'
    select @LastNameFromUser as 'LASTNAMEFROMUser'
    select 'OUTPUTPROCEDURECALLED'
    declare @maxvalue int , @finalpercentage int = 0
    DECLARE @variableTable TABLE
     (
        idx int identity(1,1),
        matchvalue nvarchar(15)
        )

        INSERT INTO @variableTable(matchvalue) values ('MiddleName')
        INSERT INTO @variableTable(matchvalue) values ('LastName')
        INSERT INTO @variableTable(matchvalue) values ('City')

        SELECT * FROM @variableTable 
    DECLARE @counter int

    declare @sql nvarchar(100)
    declare @sql2 nvarchar(25), @finalResult nvarchar(100)
    set @finalResult = 0;
    declare @sql3 nvarchar(300), @sql4 nvarchar(15),  @tempresultStore nvarchar(20), @temp int, @temp2 int, @average int
    DECLARE @ParmeterDefinition nvarchar(500);
    set @ParmeterDefinition = 
    N'@LastNameFromUsnvarchar(20), 
    @LastNameFromTab nvarchar(20), 
    @MiddleNameFromUs nvarchar(20), 
    @MiddleNameFromTab nvarchar(20), 
    @CityFromUs nvarchar(20),
    @CityFromTab nvarchar(20),
    @Percent int out'


    SET @counter = 1
    SELECT @maxvalue = (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @variableTable)

    select @maxvalue as 'MAXVALUE'
    WHILE(@counter < @maxvalue)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @colVar nvarchar(15)

        SELECT @colVar = matchvalue FROM @variableTable WHERE idx = @counter

        set @tempresultStore = 'Temp'+@colVar  --here
        SELECT @tempresultStore AS 'FINALCUTPART'
        select 'JUSTBEFORSQL'
     set @sql3 = 'declare @Temp' + @colVar + ' int = dbo.[Match' + @colVar + '](' + @colVar + 'FromUser,' + @colVar + 'FromTable, 0)' 
    select @sql3 as 'check sql query formed'
     EXEC sp_executesql @sql3, 
    @ParmeterDefinition, 
     @LastNameFromUs = @LastNameFromUser, 
    @LastNameFromTab = @LastNameFromTable, 
    @MiddleNameFromUs = @MiddleNameFromUser, 
    @MiddleNameFromTab  = @MiddleNameFromTable, 
    @CityFromUs = @CityFromUser,
    @CityFromTab  = @CityFromTable,
    @Percent =  @Percentage out
    select @Percentage AS 'PERCENTRETRIVED'
    set @finalResult = @finalResult + @Percentage  /*here @Percentage always remains 0. It is the value returned by the UDF called by the dynamic SQL above.The function does return the value but probably I fail to store it correctly.*/
   select @finalResult as 'SUM'
        SET @counter = @counter + 1
        select @counter as 'COUNTERVALUE'
        END
        set @finalpercentage = @finalResult/@maxvalue
        SELECT @finalpercentage AS 'FINALRESULT'
    RETURN 
    END
     Go
```

How do I access the int value stored in variable called `@TempMIddleName`

Comment: Try using my example below - and amend your code storing the variable into a table simply used to store results...

Comment: No offense meant here but much like your other thread this needs a complete rethinking. Instead of creating all these functions you should instead be passing parameters in, not dynamically deciding what to do. The way you are doing this is going to be horribly inefficient and completely unmaintainable in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work with output keyword. No need for creating table. I don't know but your code is not correct. You have output parameter @Percent and assign value of function to @TempMiddleName, then you should have not a @Percent as Output but @TempMiddleName.

You get dynamic SQL

```
declare @TempMiddleName int = dbo.[MatchMiddleName](MiddleNameFromUser,MiddleNameFromTable, 0)
```

I had answered you once, that you miss `@` before your variables.
Also you have provided variable @Percent(and others as well) for dynamic query, but you don't assign any value to it. Try changing

```
SET @sql3 = 'declare @Temp' + @colVar + ' int = dbo.[Match' + @colVar + '](' + @colVar + 'FromUser,' + @colVar + 'FromTable, 0)'
```

to

```
SET @sql3 = 'select @Percent = 1'
```

and you will see that 1 is returned as supposed to.

Also you have error here. Split first parameter from its type

```
set @ParmeterDefinition = 
    N'@LastNameFromUsnvarchar(20), 


 set @ParmeterDefinition = 
    N'@LastNameFromUs nvarchar(20),
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to dynamically create a temporary table, and access it's value by selecting the top 1 value from it. Something like the following;

```
CREATE TABLE #ResultValue (Value Varchar(200))

DECLARE @DynamicSql NVarchar(MAX) = ''

SELECT @DynamicSql = '

DECLARE @tempresultStore Varchar(50)
DECLARE @colVar Varchar(50) = ''MiddleName''
SET @tempresultStore = ''Temp'' + @colVar 

insert into #ResultValue
select @tempresultStore
'

EXEC sp_sqlexec @DynamicSql

SELECT * FROM #ResultValue

DROP TABLE #ResultValue
```

If you paste all your code we might try to amend it for you.

Comment: No, it would not be storing the integer value. I have mentioned, I am interested in retrieving the integer value stored in variable name @TempMiddleName